# echo a specific element from a multi-element json array

Tags: php, json

Can you anyone show me the correct syntax to echo a specific element from the snippet below?  I wish to echo the `accountName` element.  How about the `employeeId` element?

A part of the output of `var_dump($api_response)`:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (3) {
  ["responseCode"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["responseObject"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#2 (50) {
      ["accountId"]=>
      int(429987)
      ["firmId"]=>
      int(129564)
      ["accountName"]=>
      string(12) "Acme"
      ["description"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["website"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["tickerSymbol"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["rating"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["assignedTo"]=>
      object(stdClass)#3 (33) {
        ["employeeId"]=>
        int(31142)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that `responseObject` is an array, so use the array index to access the element(s) in it.

```
echo $api_response->responseObject[0]->accountName;
echo $api_response->responseObject[0]->assignedTo->employeeId;
```

if the `responseObject` contains multiple elements, use the `foreach` loop:

```
foreach($api_response->responseObject as $p)
{
    echo $p->accountName;
    echo $p->assignedTo->employeeId;
}
```